# If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple $\Rightarrow$ $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g} $ imply $\mathfrak{h} \cap \mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple  Lie Algebra, $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the Killing form, and $\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{g}$ a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

I'm trying to find a counterexample (or prove) the following affirmation:

> **Affirmation:** $\mathfrak{h} \cap \mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{0\}$,
>   where $\mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{X \in \mathfrak{g};\  \langle X, Y\rangle =0, \ \forall \ Y\in \mathfrak{h} \}$.

Does anyone know how to prove this or have a nice counterexample?

**NB:** In my opinion this affirmation seems false, however all spaces that I tried $\mathfrak{h} \cap \mathfrak{h}^\perp = \{0\}$ held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any semi-simple algebra $g$ which is not compact, the killing form is not a scalar product, there exists $x\in g$ such that $\langle x,x\rangle =0$, $Vect(x)$ is a subalgebra of $g$ and $x$ is in the orthogonal of $Vect(x)$.

Comment: How do you know that there are $x$ such that $⟨x,x⟩=0$? I did not quite understand this assertion.

Comment: because Killing is not negative define its signature is $(k,n-k)$ $k>0$.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I do not know this part of the theory yet

Comment: in this case compute the killing form of $SL(2)$ and find a vector such that $\langle x,x\rangle=0$.

Comment: I think I can solve the problem now, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just for the records. I think that $x = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $ works.

Answer (score 2):

A good example for this is parabolic subalgebras. Almost by definition they contain their Killing polars. That is let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a non-compact semisimple Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{p} \leq \mathfrak{g}$ be a parabolic subalgebra (containing a Borel subalgebra) then $\mathfrak{p}^\perp \subset \mathfrak{p}$. For a concrete example of a parabolic subalgebra just think of your favourite matrix Lie algebra and the subalgebra of upper triangular matrices.